# Ordering when using scala.collection.Searching

Tags: arrays, scala, search

I have an Array of [Long, Q] and would like to make a binary search on it. I tried below :

```
import scala.collection.Searching._
class Q (val b:Double, val a:Double)

val myArray = Array(5L -> new Q(1,2), 6L-> new Q(6,9), 7L-> new Q(7,6))
val i = myArray.search(6L).insertionPoint
```

but had this error
No implicit Ordering defined for Any
Unspecified value parameter ord.
I understand that I need to specify an odering rule for this collection Array[(Long,Q)] but can't figure this out myself.
Please help

Comment: You aren't supposed to need or use `null` in Scala, but here's a case where it might come in handy: `myArray.search(6L->null)(Ordering.by(_._1)).insertionPoint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signature of `search` is `search[B >: A](elem: B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B])`. You've got an array of type `[Long, Q]`. So in order for the compiler to infer `Ordering` correctly, you'd have to invoke search like that:

```
myArray.search(6L-> q/*Q(6,9)*/)(Ordering.by(_._1)) //ordering by the first value in a tuple.
```

and what you're doing is: `myArray.search(6L)`. If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, it's probably to find both value and position in the array.
You could solve it by using two separate data structures:

- keys could be stored in the array, like this:

  ```
  val myArray = Array(5L, 6L, 7L).toList 
  myArray.search(6L).insertionPoint
  ```
- and if you'd need values, you could use map which would work as a dictionary:

  ```
  val dictionary = Map(
     5L -> new Q(1,2),
     6L-> new Q(6,9),
     7L-> new Q(7,6)
  )
  ```

**EDIT:**

Actually, I noticed something like that would work:

```
val dummy = new Q(0,0) //any instance of Q
myArray.search(6L-> dummy)(Ordering.by(_._1)).insertionPoint //1
```

It works since for lookup of the insertion point `Ordering` is used and no equality test is performed.

Comment: Map wouldn't work because in case of non exisiting element, I see want to have the closest index, which is given by seach. Regarding your proposition, it's not clear to me why are you creating new element in myArray while searching? Moreove is it possible to define the Ordering implicitely once so not have to pass it through each time I call seach ?

Comment: You don't have to create new `Q` in search, but you have to provide one, which would equal one in an array. In case you don't have value, you will just receive `None` from the map.

Comment: but why you need to create a dummy Q. There must be a cleaner way

Comment: Because search expects `[Long, Q]`. Why do you even need array? Map wouldn't work?

Comment: I use array because I need to do a binary search. IF I look for an element that doesn't exist, I should get the index when I need to push it. 
Maps won't work in this case. Do you have another opinion ?

Comment: Why do you need a binary search? Do you need to store index or you just need to fast lookup?

Comment: I need to have the index of the value I'm searching. It it's not available, get the closed index. Do you have a better solution in mind ?

Comment: I would use the list and map. So I would try to get the index from list and then just lookup for value from map.

Comment: @Crovish If you're unsatisfied with that answer, you should probably create a bounty for this question. Maybe somebody would come with a better solution.